# Need help on writing sql select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a question about selecting rows from a table.
For example I have a table which includes information about stock movements. I wish to select the product code, latest date, latest price of each product in the table.

**Stock movements table**

```
Stock Movement Code  Product code      Date         Price
1                       1            15.06.2015     9$
2                       2            17.06.2015     10$
3                       2            18.06.2015     8$
4                       1            19.06.2015     7$
5                       3            20.06.2015     11$
6                       2            21.06.2015     12$
7                       3            22.06.2015     13$
```

I wish to select the latest date,latest price of each product from above table.

For this example I am waiting a result like below.

```
Stock Movement Code  Product code      Date         Price
4                      1               19.06.2015    7$
6                      2               21.06.2015    12$
7                      3               22.06.2015    13$
```

Could you please help me to write the SQL of this select statement?

Comment: I think your result for Product code = 1: Stock = 4. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sm.*
FROM stock_movement sm
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'NEXT'
    FROM stock_movement sm2
    WHERE sm2.[Product code] = sm.[Product code]
    AND sm2.date > sm.date
)
```